# Including variables in expression call in R

Tags: r, expression

I was wondering if it were possible to include variables when using `expression` in R.

For instance I would like to do something like this:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for (i in 1:6)
    {
    plot(x, p1-i*p2, main=expression(Phi[1] - i * Phi[2]))
    }
```

But this does not work, as it prints Φ<sub>1</sub> - iΦ<sub>2</sub> (i.e. it does not substitute `i` with `1, 2, ... 6`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use substitute:

```
> substitute(Phi[1] - i* Phi[2], list(i = i))
Phi[1] - 3 * Phi[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it uses the variables.
I set x = 1 and used the following.

```
> p1 = 100
> p2 = 10
> for (i in 1:6)
+     {
+     plot(x, p1-i*p2, main=expression(Phi[1] - i * Phi[2]))
+     }
>
```

It gave me 6 graphs for Φ1 - iΦ2 with each showing the Y value descending.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem was just the title, not the graph. :)