# Combining vector variables in R expression for plot text

Tags: r, plot, expression

I am trying to create a text layer in an R plot containing normal and superscript text that derives from variables.

So far I have this:

```
first = c("one", "two", "three")
second = c(1, 2, 3)
plot(1:3, 3:1)
text(1:3, 3:1, labels=first)
```

The way it works now, it shows one, two, etc on the plot. I want it to show one<sup>1</sup>, two<sup>2</sup>, etc.

I guess it should be some combination of `expression`, `paste`, `bquote` and maybe another function. I just can't get it to get it to read the data as vectors and make the proper superscript.

I've seen some questions on this site, for example:

- [Combining paste() and expression() functions in plot labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4973898/2104287)
- [Use expression with a variable r](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15074127/2104287)
- [Including variables in expression call in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3345625/2104287)

None of them fully answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you can try

```
 plot(1:3, 3:1)
 text(1:3, (3:1)-0.03, labels= mapply(function(x,y)
      as.expression(bquote(.(x)^.(y))), first, second))
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to do without any custom functions, but it definitely works.

Comment: @Michael Do you mean without `bquote`, `expression`, `paste` etc?